# Excel, VBA, SQL - Retrieve data from another workbook / Error

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I want to retrieve data from a closed workbook.
My code is

```
fileName = "the path\test.xlsx"
With CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    .CommandTimeout = 500
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
        & fileName & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Readonly=true"";"
    .Open
      ThisWorkbooks.Worksheets("new").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset .Execute("select * from [source$B1]")
    .Close
End With
```

I have some error, 424:object required, object doesn't found... I think it is a syntax problem.
The purpose is to retrieve data from cells and put in the other sheet/workbook
thanks for your help

Comment: I am not sure if it is the SQL, what line errors?

Comment: ThisWorkbooks.Worksheets("new").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset .Execute("select * from [source$B1]")

Comment: Have you done any debugging?  Like does the SQL return a recordset, is new a sheet?  Is the connection open?

Comment: How can I know if the connection is open? There is no change on my sheet "new"

Comment: It is the right way to retrieve the value of the cell B1 (closed workbook, sheet "source") and put it in the cell A1 (current workbook, sheet "new")

Comment: I believe so, but not sure that the SQL is correct, does the sheet source exist also, I am not sure if it should be `$B1:B1`

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("new").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset .Execute("select * from [source$B1:B1]")

Comment: No error with that, but nothing in the "new" sheet. How can I know if the request return something? Thanks

Comment: is there anything in the cell in the closed sheet?   Try a test say, just having "ABCDEF" in the cell and trying it.

Comment: Change `HDR` to  "No". See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan_Sav and jblood94, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. Unless you defined "ThisWorkbooks" somewhere, I think it should be "ThisWorkbook".
2. Using this method, I have only ever been able to fetch ranges that contain ":" in them, so change `source$B1` to `source$B1:B1`.
3. Since you only want one cell, you should turn the `HDR` (header) option off.

   ```
   fileName = "the path\test.xlsx"

   With CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
       .CommandTimeout = 500
       .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
       & fileName & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;Readonly=true"";"
       .Open
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("new").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset 
       .Execute("select * from [source$B1:B1]")
       .Close
   End With
   ```

Comment: There is no error now, thanks a lot ! but nothing in the cell A1 of the "new" sheet. Maybe the request return nothing but there is a value in the cell B1 of the sheet "source"

Comment: @NCall Updated with a fix for `HDR`.